# using unput wrong

Tags: c, parsing, lex, flex-lexer

I created test.l, input to flex, which ends with the main function.

When the main function is implemented as:

```
int
main(void)
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem.

I want to trick the parser into believing that the first character is always a semi-colon, so I implemented main as

```
int
main(void)
{
    unput(';');
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

the above leads to a segment fault.

Why does the use of unput lead to a segment fault?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is causing a segment fault because yylex() has not yet initialized the input buffers etc. that are needed by unput().

There's probably a better way to design your scanner without needing to trick it into a leading semicolon, but if you must do this then one solution might be to use start conditions.  Something like this:

```
%x SPECIAL
%%
    BEGIN(SPECIAL); /* Go to SPECIAL state when yylex first called */

<SPECIAL>.  { unput(*yytext); unput(';'); BEGIN(INITIAL); }

... rest of rules ...
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I wanted to run at the beginning just once, I couldn't figure out how, now I do not need to resort to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not wrong in meaning.

```
int main(void) { unput(';'); yylex(); return 0; }
```

The problem came from flex which declared the `unput` macro and of course you should have initialized lex before.

But if you put your main outside of the `.l file`, your code will not segfault.